# ERROR: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Tags: database, oracle, service, window, tnsnames

Hi after I had a Windows update today my Oracle database doesn't start any more. I tried different solutions with the same topic on this website but so far nothing has worked.

1. When I connect with SQL*Plus I get:

   ERROR:
   ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
2. When I check my services

[image]
I don't see my listener my anymore...

3. My listener.ora

[image]

4. lsnrctl services && lsnrctl status (both)

`TNS-12541: TNS:no listener`
`TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error`
`TNS-00511: No listener`
`64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error`

**In the end:**

**Nothing has changed before the update...**

**Everything worked great until the update...**

**UPDATE 20/07/2019 12:03**

After I tried the solution:  liberidu.com/blog/2015/12/07/howto-unable-to-openscmanager-err5

Now I am getting:
a new service:
[image]

And
[image]

When I am connecting with sql/plus I am still getting the message:
ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

But when I connect with PlSQL Developer
I am getting:ORA-12518, TNS:listener could not hand off client connection

Comment: What happens when you try to start the listener? Is the database up?

Comment: Hi Robert,Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

Unable to OpenSCManager: err=5
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error

Comment: Not seen this before but this person seemed to have the same issue: http://www.liberidu.com/blog/2015/12/07/howto-unable-to-openscmanager-err5/

Comment: UPDATE: I am trying the solution from the blog thank you very much Robert, now I am getting tns listener could not hand off client connection  for the moment I am still debugging it. If I have more update I will write soon :)

Comment: Sadly nothing ...

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots. Provide error messages and settings as formatted text.

Comment: Ok, I will do that. For the moment is there a way to export my database files by not connecting to sql/plus ?

Answer (score 2):

Check if you **RUN the CMD as ADMINISTRATOR**, in my case after run cmd as administrator, it works.

Run CMD Without Admin (got error TNS-00530):

```
C:\Users\me>LSNRCTL.EXE start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 01-AUG-2020 17:43:44

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

Unable to OpenSCManager: err=5
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error
```

Run CMD as Admin:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>LSNRCTL.EXE start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 01-AUG-2020 17:36:24

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

Enter User's password :
TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
...
...
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "ORCL" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCL", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: This works. I was running lsnrctl as a non-admin user. Without admin rights, starting the tns listener fails with a vague error which isn't very helpful.

Comment: Not worked for me as I am getting `Service OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener already running.`

Answer (score 1):

this error appears on windows, you need to start the service associated to the instanceName.

and in addition, you need to register de instance_name or service_name to the listener ir order to be listened on listener on port 1521 or another port.

this can be done using dynamic registration with local_listener parameter pointing to IP 192.168.1.5 port 1521. with something like this: alter system set local_listener=  ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=1521)) ';

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If "tnsnames.ora" and "listener.ora" files looks fine and still you are getting errors then try the following simple steps

```
Go to start->Run [windows button + r]
Type "services.msc"
From the services window, try to find "OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener"
Just right click on it and click on "start"
Check the status in command prompt [c:\windows\System32> lsnrctl status]
```

hope the listener listens !

Try to open up the database now

Answer (score 0):

Check information in dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora

Use machine name or ip in Host and provide configured port

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ???)(PORT = ???))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )